# How do I copy color formatting with Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

In short, the title.

I'm trying to copy-paste parts of a word document to another location, and the receiving location doesn't get the colors pasted in. When I copy and paste to notepad and notepad++ to see what's going on, there's no color formatting pasted over.

How can I get my copy-paste to properly pick up the font colors from Word, to paste in other locations?

Comment: It depends on te color. It may be a theme color which could change depending on the applicable theme. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Themes If you want, save a document with the passage involved and the color you want copied in a cloud location and paste a link here. It does not surprise me that this does not pass throughh NotePad or NotePade++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying, right-click Paste when selecting Keep Source Formatting.

[image]